# https only works for https://localhost, not from outside

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8.5

It worked yesterday.

This morning I added the `asp.net` users/roles database to an aws rds instance. Works fine on my computer, but when I deploy it to an aws ec2 server(windows server 2012, iis 8.5) the `https` doesn't work. I don;t think i did anything else.

Bindings are `*:443` and `*:80`.

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed

Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 19.05.31.337

[Fiddler] The connection to '--' failed. <br />Error: TimedOut (0x274c).
```

Comment: Does your Amazon EC2 security policy permit access to 80/TCP and 443/TCP from your source IP(s)? While you might be listening for traffic for those ports on your server, remote hosts might be having their traffic filtered.

Comment: That was it. Thank you, Paul Calabro!
Didn't think to look there at all. It worked yesterday and I had only changed things on the server(I think).

Comment: Happy to help. I converted the comment to an answer. Please accept it if it resolved the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Amazon EC2 security policy permit access to 80/TCP and 443/TCP from your source IP(s)? While you might be listening for traffic for those ports on your server, remote hosts might be having their traffic filtered.